# I'm getting error while uploading file to the database using spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, xampp

"com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.PacketTooBigException: Packet for query is too large (1,545,476 > 1,048,576). You can change this value on the server by setting the 'max_allowed_packet' variable."

I changed "max_allowed_packet= 16MB" but still I'm getting an error I mentioned in the upper line.

Comment: Can you try 16M only instead of 16MB

Comment: yes I used only 16M instead of 16MB

Comment: Did it work after doing that?

Comment: no, it is not working